# Convert the results of a dictironary to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

From this commands

```
from stackapi import StackAPI
lst = ['11786778','12370060']
df = pd.DataFrame(lst)
SITE = StackAPI('stackoverflow', key="xxxx")
results = []
for i in range(1,len(df)):
    SITE.max_pages=10000000
    SITE.page_size=100
    post = SITE.fetch('/users/{ids}/reputation-history', ids=lst[i])
    results.append(post)
```

The results variable prints the results of the json format
How is it possible to converts the results variable to a dataframe with five columns?

> reputation_history_type, reputation_change, post_id, creation_date,
>   user_id

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns=['col1', 'col2', ..etc]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here try this  :

```
from stackapi import StackAPI
import pandas as pd
lst = ['11786778','12370060']
SITE = StackAPI('stackoverflow')
results = []
SITE.max_pages=10000000
SITE.page_size=100
for i in lst:
    post = SITE.fetch('/users/{ids}/reputation-history', ids=[i]).get('items')
    results.extend([list(j.values()) for j in post])
df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns = ['reputation_history_type', 'reputation_change', 'post_id', 'creation_date', 'user_id'])
```

**Output** :

`print(df.head())` gives :

```
  reputation_history_type  reputation_change   post_id  creation_date     user_id
0    asker_accepts_answer                  2  59126012     1575207944  11786778.0
1        post_undownvoted                  2  59118819     1575139301  11786778.0
2            post_upvoted                 10  59118819     1575139301  11786778.0
3          post_downvoted                 -2  59118819     1575139299  11786778.0
4            post_upvoted                 10  59110166     1575094452  11786778.0
```

`print(df.tail())` gives :

```
    reputation_history_type  reputation_change   post_id  creation_date     user_id
170            post_upvoted                 10  58906292     1574036540  12370060.0
171         answer_accepted                 15  58896536     1573990105  12370060.0
172            post_upvoted                 10  58896044     1573972834  12370060.0
173          post_downvoted                  0  58896299     1573948372  12370060.0
174          post_downvoted                  0  58896158     1573947435  12370060.0
```

**NOTE** :

1. You can just create a dataframe direct from the result which will be list of lists.
2. You don't need to declare `SITE.max_page` and `SIZE.page_size` every time you loop through the `lst`.

Answer (score 1):

```
from stackapi import StackAPI
import pandas as pd
lst = ['11786778', '12370060']
df = pd.DataFrame(lst)
SITE = StackAPI('stackoverflow', key="xxxx")
results = []
for i in range(1, len(df)):
    SITE.max_pages = 10000000
    SITE.page_size = 100
    post = SITE.fetch('/users/{ids}/reputation-history', ids=lst[i])
    results.append(post)
data = []
for item in results:
    data.append(item)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['reputation_history_type', 'reputation_change', 'post_id', 'creation_date', 'user_id']
print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

Kinda flying in the blind since I maxed out my StackOverflow API limit, but this *should* work:

```
from stackapi import StackAPI
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

lst = ['11786778','12370060']
SITE = StackAPI('stackoverflow', key="xxx")

results = []
for ids in lst:
    SITE.max_pages=10000000
    SITE.page_size=100
    post = SITE.fetch('/users/{ids}/reputation-history', ids=ids)
    results.append(json_normalize(post, 'items'))

df = pd.concat(results, ignore_index=True)
```

- `json_normalize` converts the JSON to dataframe
- `pd.concat` concatenates the dataframes together to make a single frame